# What's going on with my onclick function for my submit button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's what I'm trying to do for my project. I have a simple content box wrapped in a div tag. There are paragraphs added in and have their own id for rules on their own. I've set the margins, the padding, so on and so on. Then at the bottom, I've added a typical submit button. What I labeled that was show more. With overflow going on inside my content box, I want to increase the height so that it can show the rest of the text. However, when I add in the onclick command with the anonymous function with if/else statements, things get a bit jarring.

Here's the HTML code first.

```js
    var content = document.getElementById('contentbox');
    var button = document.getElementById('showMore');
    
    button.onclick = function() {
     if(content.className == "open") {
      content.className = "";
     } else {
      content.className = "open";
     }
    };
```

```css
    body {
     padding:0;
     margin:0;
     font-family:sans-serif;
    }
    
    #contentbox {
     margin:100px 300px 100px 300px;
     border:1px solid black;
     padding:5px 0px 5px 20px;
     max-height:200px;
     overflow:hidden;
     background:silver;
     border-radius:10px;
    
    }
    #contentbox.open {
     max-height:1000px;
     overflow:visible;
    }
    #content {
     color:white;
     font-size:20px;
     text-indent:30px;
    }
    
    #showMore {
     margin-left:auto;
     margin-right:auto;
     display:block;
     background:gray;
     font-size:40px;
     text-transform:uppercase;
     font-family:impact;
     color:silver;
     transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    }
    #showMore:hover {
     color:gray;
     background:silver;
     cursor:pointer;
    }
```

```html
      <html>
    <head>
     <title>Kenneth's new HTML/CSS Exercise</title>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='contentbox.css'>
     <script src="stuff.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="contentbox">
    <p id="content">
    this is a bunch of text for you to read and Game of Thrones is an American fantasy drama television series created by David Benioff and D. B. Weiss. It is an adaptation of A Song of Ice and Fire, George R. R. Martin's series of fantasy novels, the first of which is A Game of Thrones. It is filmed at Titanic Studios in Belfast, on location in the United Kingdom, and in Croatia, Iceland, Malta, Morocco, Spain, and the United States. The series premiered on HBO in the United States on April 17, 2011, and its sixth season ended on June 26, 2016. The series was renewed for a seventh season,[1] which is scheduled to premiere on July 16, 2017.[2] The series will conclude with its eighth season in 2018 </p>
    
    <p id='content'> Set on the fictional continents of Westeros and Essos, Game of Thrones has several plot lines and a large ensemble cast. The first story arc follows a dynastic conflict among competing claimants for succession to the Iron Throne of the Seven Kingdoms, with other noble families fighting for independence from the throne. The second covers attempts to reclaim the throne by the exiled last scion of the realm's deposed ruling dynasty; the third chronicles the threat of the impending winter and the legendary creatures and fierce peoples of the North. </p>
    
    <p id='content'> Game of Thrones has attracted record viewership on HBO and has a broad, active, international fan base. It has been acclaimed by critics, particularly for its acting, complex characters, story, scope, and production values, although its frequent use of nudity and violence (including sexual violence) has attracted criticism. The series has received 38 Primetime Emmy Awards, including Outstanding Drama Series in 2015 and 2016, more than any other primetime scripted television series. Its other awards and nominations include three Hugo Awards for Best Dramatic Presentation (2012–2014), a 2011 Peabody Award, and four nominations for the Golden Globe Award for Best Television Series – Drama (2012 and 2015–2017). Of the ensemble cast, Peter Dinklage has won two Primetime Emmy Awards for Outstanding Supporting Actor in a Drama Series (2011 and 2015) and the Golden Globe Award for Best Supporting Actor – Series, Miniseries or Television Film (2012) for his performance as Tyrion Lannister. Lena Headey, Emilia Clarke, Kit Harington, Maisie Williams, Diana Rigg, and Max von Sydow have also received Primetime Emmy Award nominations for their performances in the series. </p>
    
    </div>
    
    <input type='submit' value='Show more' id="showMore"></input>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

What's going on and what do I have to do to fix it?

Comment: submit buttons submit

Comment: huh? What exactly do you mean?

Comment: submit button submits the page so the state of the page is reset.

Comment: That's not true @epascarello the button on click is not submitting a form.

Comment: @SeanNewell So `type="submit"` does not submit? `<input type='submit' value='Show more' id="showMore">`

Comment: It could be true, so your point might be valid in a different context. If the button was in a form tag, then the on click handler should return false so the form does not get submitted. But the submit input is not in a form.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

```
var content = document.getElementById('contentbox');
var button = document.getElementById('showMore');

button.onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //do your logic
    if(content.className == "open") {
        content.className = "";
    } else {
        content.className = "open";
    }
    //
};
```

In that way you prevent submit event that skip your logic.
But you need to submit form manually after all actions in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Set it to height not Max height
hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Here's what is happening.

The `.open` styles *overflow: visible* property makes it so that the text keeps getting drawn by the browser even after the max height of the box. You probably don't want that.

If you do this instead, height will be calculated based on content.

```
#contentbox.open {
  height: auto;
  max-height: initial;
}
```

[Working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oqn8386f/)

The overflow property shouldn't be changed unless you want to change *scroll* behavior (usually). The max-height initial will override the maximum height.

If you want a scroll bar instead, do this:

```
#contentbox.open {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

And you can change the max-height if you wanted to still.

Hope that was a good explanation.

---

Other users have pointed out that your button is a submission button. That may cause problems because it could trigger a page load, nullifying anything you're trying to do. On the previous jsfiddle link the button does not submit a form, so the code works as is (without returning false, changing the button type, or stopping propagation).

But you might want to change your click handler to return false if you are not submitting a form, like this [paste bin](http://pastebin.com/KrDVaKNy) shows (which is an all-in-one solution just like the jsfiddle).

Or, you could remove the `type='submit'` from your button, I think that would work too.

Comment: It didn't work at all for some reason. Any other thing that might work?

Comment: That worked for me on a jsfiddle. Look in the debugger (F12) and inspect the element to see computed styles. Something might be overriding it. I'll get a js fiddle of the working solution.

Comment: Added ze fiddle.

Comment: I see where you're coming from now. I actually did this the good ole fashion way and tried this out on sublime text and then opened it through my browser on explorer and chrome. Both aren't working.

Comment: Yeah you'll have to do some hunting in chrome's dev tools. I'll try it in a single file with sublime and chrome and see if I can find the issue too.

Comment: @KennethMcAusland Sorry about the previous link, switched to trusty pastebin. Here is a [all-in-one html file](http://pastebin.com/KrDVaKNy) that works on my chrome. Made it in sublime.

Comment: I'll get on top of it sometime tomorrow afternoon. Work is coming up. If you can, try to get back at me sometime around 3pm central.